# Img disappears when adding text to <p>

Tags: image, function, text

I want to add some dynamic text in a

element within a div that also contains an image, however the image disappears when the text is added. My function is in a click event handler and performs as expected except for the disappearing image. I know this is simple but as self-taught what seems simple is not always for me.

HTML

CSS
    #score-message {
      position:absolute;
      width:20%;
      height:200px;
      background-color:#8FBC8F;
    }

JQ function

```
function score_message(score) {
  if(score == 5) {
var message = "Congratulations, etc, etc";
$('#score-message').first('p').text(message).show().offset({top:300, left:850});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is within that first "p" tag then by calling text you are overwriting it.  Try this:

```
var pTag = $('#score-message').first('p');
pTag.html(pTag.html() + " HA! HA! HA! YOU A WINNER!!!");
```

Note the use of html instead of text also.  I believe text will strip markup or at least not treat it as such and escape it or something.

You could also do something like:

```
pTag.append(" HA! HA! HA! YOU A WINNER!!!");
```

Comment: I didn't try the html method because the documentation states this: When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Let me try.

Comment: I'm sure the same thing applies to text. In either of them you are saying "set my content to this".  And it does just that, overwriting what was there previously.

Comment: From jquery docs for text(content): "Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text" -- This implies replacement of all content. Also, going with what I said in the answer: "We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as HTML"